# OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, oauth-2.0

I am using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware for ASP.Net Core application to authenticate against Dells Cloud access manager token provider (setup to provide OpenId/OAuth2 authentication). Following is the code:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            AuthenticationScheme = "ClientCookie",
            CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "ClientCookie",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/signin"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/signout")
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            SaveTokens = true,
            ClientId = "XYZClient_Id",
            ClientSecret = "XYZ_ClientSecret",
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://example.com",
            Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration {
                AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://CAM.COM/CloudAccessManager/RPSTS/OAuth2/Default.aspx",
                TokenEndpoint = "https://CAM.COM/CloudAccessManager/RPSTS/OAuth2/Token.aspx",
                UserInfoEndpoint = "https://CAM.COM/CloudAccessManager/RPSTS/OAuth2/User.aspx",
                Issuer= "urn:CAM.COM/CloudAccessManager/RPSTS",
            }
        });
```

But I am stuck at one point for a few hours now. I get the following error:

SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. There are no security keys to use to validate the signature

I am getting code and state back in url querystring
https://example.com/signin-oidc?code=somecode&state=somestate

Any type of guidance is appreciated.

---

UPDATE 
Added Issuer Signing key:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:ClientSecret")))
                }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error you're seeing is caused by the fact you're not using the [OpenID Connect provider configuration discovery feature](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) offered by the OIDC middleware, that allows it to retrieve the cryptographic keys used to sign identity tokens.

If your provider supports this feature, remove the entire `Configuration` node and set `Authority` instead. All the endpoints should be automatically registered for you.

If it doesn't support this feature, you'll have to manually add the signing keys to `OpenIdConnectOptions.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys`.

Comment: This saved a lot of my time and can get started with manually adding the signing keys since my provider does not provide a configuration discovery end point. Also thank you for the instant reply

Comment: What if I get the same error message but have no `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` and instead am using `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` on my `AddAuthentication()`? That's the Azure based and today recommended MIP (Microsoft Identity Platform).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the Scope was wrong, to fix it I appended a **.default** at the end.

```
"Scopes": "https://Company.onmicrosoft.com/OAuth2.POC.MicroServiceAPI/.default"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your OpenID Connect Provider did not send a `state` parameter in its response alongside the authentication code. However, `state` is a mandatory parameter if it was included in the request URL sent to the OpenID Connect provider (see these [docs](https://curity.io/resources/learn/openid-code-flow/)).

If the OpenID Connect Provider works as expected. that means the `state` value was not sent in the login request URL. In my case that happened because I used the wrong login request URL and modified my backend response in `OpenIdConnectOptions.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`.