# OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException: IDX10320

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, oauth-2.0

I have [configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601672/openidconnectauthenticationhandler-message-state-is-null-or-empty) OpenIdConnect middleware for ASP Net Core application but am getting the following error in multiple cases: 
One being multiple tabs with different URLs getting claims from the same token provider (Don't really know what sequence of events cause the issue). 
Two, after leaving the web site untouched for a few minutes(session expires) and the application redirects to token provider to authenticate again after trying to access a MVC controller with a authorization attribute:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException:
>   IDX10320: RequireNonce is 'True' but
>   OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce is null. A nonce cannot
>   be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set
>   OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.ValidateNonce(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext
>   validationContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.ValidateTokenResponse(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext
>   validationContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.d__19.MoveNext()

The URL at this exception is http://localhost:64317/signin-oidc?code=UnEgtrrejMnTGxHgGiCqvuiq&state=CfDJ8HhVWymkQB5Moz...

I saw that the token returned from the token provider did not contain nonce value which I usually get.

Comment: It seems you get error like https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1695

Comment: @ademcaglin I did go through that issue but there is no concrete solution mentioned and none of it worked for me