# ASP.NET Core: OpenIdConnect: message.State is null or empty

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

I get this error:

> OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.

with the URL `https://localhost:7208/home/index`, but the authentication works with the url `https://localhost:7208/`.

Can anyone help me understand this?

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

`Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{

});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddCookie(options =>
{

})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["OpenIdConfigurations:Authority"];
    options.MetadataAddress = builder.Configuration["OpenIdConfigurations:MetadataAddress"];
    options.ResponseType = builder.Configuration["OpenIdConfigurations:ResponseType"];
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = Convert.ToBoolean(builder.Configuration["OpenIdConfigurations:GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint"]);
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(builder.Configuration["OpenIdConfigurations:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["OpenIdConfigurations:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["OpenIdConfigurations:ClientSecret"];
    options.CallbackPath = builder.Configuration["OpenIdConfigurations:CallbackPath"];
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

app.Run();
```

Controller:

```
namespace OIDCMVC.Controllers
{
   [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Note: We use a private provide and expects the call back path.
Callbackpath = "/home/index"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601672/openidconnectauthenticationhandler-message-state-is-null-or-empty)

Comment: Still struck with the same issue

Comment: I would put app.UseAuthentication(); after UseRouting() and also why do you set CallbackPath  and what is the value of it?

Comment: I have moved the app.UseAuthentication() after UseRouthing and the reason for me to set callbackpath is we have a private provider and expects callback path.

Comment: Hi @AjayKumar, did you check this [github issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26932#issuecomment-709422116)?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, was this resolved

Answer (score 8):

I've been integrating multiple custom policies (different flows) in a single app. Removing `CallbackPath` didn't work as request were coming there from multiple sources, not just the default sign in policy. We were receiving "message.State is null or empty" page, but after navigating to the base path of the app, the user was authenticated and properly logged in.

What ultimately helped was setting `SkipUnrecognizedRequests` property to `true`:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    ...
    options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
});
```

or using appsettings:

```
{
  ...
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "",
    "Domain": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    ...
    "SkipUnrecognizedRequests": true
  },
  ...
}
```

According to the [OpenIdConnectOptions.SkipUnrecognizedRequests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.skipunrecognizedrequests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-openidconnect-openidconnectoptions-skipunrecognizedrequests) documentation:

> Indicates if requests to the CallbackPath may also be for other components. If enabled the handler will pass requests through that do not contain OpenIdConnect authentication responses. Disabling this and setting the CallbackPath to a dedicated endpoint may provide better error handling. This is disabled by default.

Also, maybe related issue here: [OIDC handler running on '/' crashes even with SkipUnrecognizedRequests set to true #10028](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10028)

Comment: thanks so much, this works for me. In my case I was handling the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event on my own

Answer (score 4):

In my case I am using blazor (.net 6) and trying to protect hangfire with Microsoft oauth. To get the auth screen of microsoft login when locating to /hangfire. The solution to this error was as simple as removing **CallbackPath** from my settings:

```
// settings found under Azure AD -> App Registration -> Your registration
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "domain", // found under Branding and properties -> publisher domain like : ...outlook.onmicrosoft.com
  "TenantId": "tenantid", // found under Overview Directory (tenant) ID GUID
  "ClientId": "client_id" // found under Overview Application (client) ID GUID
  //"CallbackPath": "/hangfire" REMOVED To get rid off message.State is null error
}
```

The setup from Program.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Hangfire", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});
services.AddHangfire(x =>
{
    x.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString);
    x.UseConsole();
});
services.AddHangfireServer();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions()
    {
        Authorization = new List<IDashboardAuthorizationFilter> { new HangfireAuthorizeFilter() },

    }).RequireAuthorization("Hangfire");
});
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

Authorization filter:
public class HangfireAuthorizeFilter:

```
IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        var userIdentity = context.GetHttpContext().User.Identity;
        return userIdentity is { IsAuthenticated: true };
    }
}
```

And the app registration from **Azure AD**:

Under your app registration click: Authentication -> Mark "ID tokens" and enter your redirect urls, like: https://localhost:52908/hangfire

Comment: Thanks!  I just had a similar issue on an IIS Hosted Site and removing the CallbackPath was exactly what fixed it!